# ¿Por qué la imagen del background se muestra abajo? laravel dompdf

Tags: css, laravel, dompdf

Tengo un problema que estoy intentando resolver pero si alguien podría echarme una mano...
El problema es que cuando genero un pdf al cual le estoy diciendo que el background tendrá X propiedades y a su vez el cuerpo tendrá X párrafos con X propiedades de CSS, el background se abajo por las propiedades CSS que tiene el párrafo.
Controllador:

```
public function obtenerdiploma()
{
    //enviar variables de esta manera
    $today = Carbon::now()->format('d/m/Y');
    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('Frontend.obtenerdiploma.obtenerdiploma', compact('today'))->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
    return $pdf->download('ejemplo.pdf');
}
```

Vista:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
        body{
            background: url('/images/diploma2.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center center;
            background-size: 100%;
        }
        h1{
        margin-top: 295px;
        margin-left: 255px;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
        }
        p{
            margin-top: 70px;
            margin-left: 218px;
            font-size: 25px;
        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO.</h1>
        <p>Ha participado del D de M del YYYY al D de M de YYYY en el curso</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Dado este código la imagen del background se muestra para abajo y el texto en su sitio, en principio el background no deberia irse para abajo...
Mi única solución es añadir 
 para posicionarlo donde quiero pero hay alguna solución para no añadir 
?

Comment: Por favor no coloques solucionado al título de tu pregunta, con aceptar la respuesta que te dio la solución alcanza

Comment: Está bien. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución a este pequeño problema que tenía, lo he encontrado en esta url de stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649052/print-margins-in-dompdf
La idea es añadir la siguiente propiedad CSS dentro del body que es donde se encuentra el background.
E incluir en el css `@page{margin:0px;}`

```
body{margin: 0px;}
@page {margin:0px;}
```

Comment: Por favor considera marcar como aceptada tu respuesta y de ese modo indicar que ya está resuelta tu publicación